# Notation for subsequence formed by deleting all occurrences of an element from another sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Supposing I have some sequence S, what's the best notation for describing the subsequence S' formed by deleting all elements of S equal to some x?

E.g., if S = (a, x, b, x), where a ≠ x and b ≠ x, the subsequence S' would be (a, b).

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard notation for this as far as I know. You can consider using $S_x$ for the new sequence, or even something like $S-x$, as long as you define the notation in your writing.